# PostBackUrls not working in Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using PostBackUrls in ASP.NET which work fine in Chrome and IE. Nothing happens when I select a button that has a PostBackUrl in Firefox. How can I make this work? Is there a bit of code that can be applied to all postbacks that I can add without the need of changing each of them individually? Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

- Do you have any other script errors in the page happening in Firefox? They might be preventing your button from working.
- Are you trying to open a window? It might've been caught by the popup blocker.
- Failing that, you can use firebug or the error console to try to locate any errors which might also be preventing your button from working.